# Issues with nVidia GeForce 210 while watching movies

Tags: 10.10, drivers, nvidia

Ever since 10.04 I have been trying to resolve an issue with my graphics card - nVidia GeForce 210.

I'm having issues when I watch movies on 10.10 - they are jumping all the time, even with Compiz disabled and when that is the only thing I am doing.

I have tried the solution to [How to get NVidia GeForce GT 210 drivers working on Lucid Lynx?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4954/how-to-get-nvidia-geforce-gt-210-drivers-working-on-lucid-lynx) but it didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Here are the steps I took:

1. `apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
2. edit `/etc/default/grub` to add the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"`
3. `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot
5. Download official Linux drivers from nVidia site.
6. `sh filename-of-downloaded-driver-package`

Comment: Please edit your question to explain the exact steps you went through in your attempt to solve the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if there are drivers available in the Proprietary Drivers thing?  In 10.04, its located at `System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers`.  There might be drivers there for your system that were packaged already.

Comment: @Pheonix - 10x for the reply. I did check. And there available drivers. Every time I try this (including on a fresh install ~two weeks ago - after reboot, X won't come up. I'm left with the shell.

Comment: @David:  You seem to not be the only one.  The same issue occurs with ATI drivers on 10.10.  I just confirmed this in a virtual environment emulating an nVidia GeForce card.  At this point, this sounds like an error with Ubuntu itself.  Have you filed a bug about it?

Comment: I haven't actually. The net seemed to be all too well familiar with that. It has to do something with the nouveau kernel module. Since Lucid, it comes with the kernel (and every update herein). Some tutorials have been written about this, by good people. Only problem is - they don't work for me. Even on a fresh fully updated install - on my monster QuadCore well-endowed computer. :(

Comment: could be a billion different reasons then, sorry I cant be of more help.  :/