# Backup systems config files

Tags: 10.10, drivers, nvidia, backup

I'm planning on installing nVidia proprietary drivers on my Ubuntu 10.10.
Historically this always ends-up with me being left with no graphical interface.  No ability to revert - and reinstalling the whole system.

So now, before trying this anew, I wish to backup all relevant config files.
I'll try 1 or 2 methods. I'll list each one's commands.
I'll appreciate if anyone can tell me how to backup the relevant file, or what's the reverse of this operation.
10x, David

Method I - as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4954/how-to-get-nvidia-geforce-gt-210-drivers-working-on-lucid-lynx):

1. apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
2. As described in this answer: edit /etc/default/grub and add the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
3. sudo update-grub
4. Reboot
5. Install original drivers downloaded from nVidia site.

Method II - as described [here](http://trycatch.iblogger.org/tips-n-tricks/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx):

1. sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
2. [possibly 'sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf' adding 'vga16fb' 'nouveau'
3. sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx-185
4. sudo modprobe nvidia
5. sudo lsmod | grep -i nvidia
6. sudo nvidia-xconfig

Answer (score 2):

For the first method, you'll need to backup /etc/default/grub, eg with

> sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup

If you edit the grub file, you'll need to run `sudo update-grub`. Nouveau can be reinstalled with `sudo apt-get reinstall xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`. Uninstall instruciton for nVidia's original driver should be included in the download, probably something similar to `sudo make uninstall`.

For the second method, you'll need to remove the edit from the blacklist file and run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-glx-185` to uninstall nVidia driver.

Comment: Please accept this answer, so this question won't show as unanswered in the frontpage.