# no video after new drivers

Tags: drivers, video

running Ubuntu 11.10 and after updating video driver it stops loading after (fail) on LightDM display manager. I can get to the command prompt but don't know any of the commands. I've been reading and tried a few things, but nothing has worked. This has happened twice. The first time I just gave up and
 reloaded Ubuntu.

I am very new to Ubuntu.

My system is an old socket 754 AMD system I built that still uses AGP for video. My video card is a 6600GT. I have a gig of memory. The mother board is a Gigabyte K8ns. Every thing was running great till I tried to use the nvidia driver.

I went to Nvidia's site later on a different computer and downloaded the driver it called for. How do you install it or is there an easier way?

Comment: you might see if this question helps : http://askubuntu.com/questions/3024/good-nvidia-drivers-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

been fighting the NVIDIA drivers myself....

I tried to install an NVIDIA driver, and it bailed on me -- Hung before beginning lightDM. Luckily, it should back up your xorg.conf automatically, which is what causes the problem.  When it boots and begins to hang, do control+alt+f1 to make a terminal.  If you tried to isntall an NVIDIA driver from their site and after running, it would not start LightDM, Login and run the following two commands.

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Hope this helps!

Comment: All I got was (No such file or directory). I didn't install the drivers from the Nvidia site. I couldn't figure out how to install it.

Comment: Alright, if its not from Nvidia, there will be no backup file.  Try perhaps installing nouveau drivers with apt-get install? (`sudo apt-get install nouveau-firmware` I think)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I gave up and reloaded Ubuntu and will do some reading before I try to update the driver again. I gotta learn how to fix things if I'm going to run Ubuntu.

Comment: I feel your pain. This is the 5th install in 2 days.