# After Nvidia drivers installed, GUI not starting

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xubuntu, xorg

No clue why, but my computer crapped out after playing TF2, so I looked online. X.org couldn't find displays, so I did what a person said and they said reinstall the drivers for the GPU (GeForce 210). I uninstall them, reboot, and the GUI works as normal, but at 800x600 with no options to change. I install the drivers again (nvidia-340) and reboot. Now I'm back to square one.

Can someone help?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1(F1 to F6) and then enter this command 'lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' ' What is the output?

Comment: What did this do? It showed my GPU and showed the kernel driver in use is "Nvidia".

Comment: Full output please. You can edit the question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to deactivate the interface and run:

```
sudo startx
```

Comment: I get an error saying "no screens found(EE)".

Comment: i found something in here: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/228212/no-desktop-after-installation-of-nvidia-drivers?rq=1

and here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers

Comment: This did nothing for me. It is literally telling me the same stuff that I said I already did (reinstall drivers).